# How can I post data to the server when my app is be Terminated?

Tags: ios

How can I post data to the server when my app is be Terminated ? I use the NSURLSession class. I try to post data when applicationWillTerminate is running but it doesn't work.

Comment: That's too late. Do it when your app enters the background.

Answer (score 2):

`applicationWillTerminate` is not meant for such tasks and  you may not have enough time to perform the actions related to server.

[Refer this apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate?language=objc)

> This method lets your app know that it is about to be terminated and
>   purged from memory entirely. You should use this method to perform any
>   final clean-up tasks for your app, such as freeing shared resources,
>   saving user data, and invalidating timers. Your implementation of this
>   method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return.
>   If the method does not return before time expires, the system may kill
>   the process altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Use `applicationDidEnterBackground` method for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the other legitimate answers, you could try sending the data when the application enters the background, but in some cases the app may be terminated before the request completes. An alternative could be to store the data (depending on what your data consists of) locally (i.e. `NSUserDefaults`) and then make the request when the app is opened at some point in the future. An obvious caveat is that if the user is accessing the data from multiple clients like a website or another device, you will need to reconcile this when you make your request.